# Why is Jquery animate() not working in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have the following HTML layout:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="fluid-container">
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                ...
            </div>
        </header>
        <section class="salutation fluid-container">
            <div class="intro-wrapper">
                ...
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

My objective is to hide intro-wrapper whenever my window scrolls more than 60px and vice-versa. Hence I have implemented the following Jquery code to achieve the above.

```
var checkScroll = true;

$(window).scroll(function() {

    if($(this).scrollTop() > 60 && checkScroll) {
        $(".intro-wrapper").stop().animate({display:'none'}, 400);
        checkScroll = false;
        console.log('Scrolling down. \t checkScroll: ' + checkScroll);
    } 

    else if($(this).scrollTop() < 60 && !checkScroll) {
        $(".intro-wrapper").stop().animate({display:'block'}, 400);
        checkScroll = true;
        console.log('Scrolling up. \t\t checkScroll: ' + checkScroll);
    }
});
```

But unfortunately, I have been failing miserably at understanding why the animation isn't taking place. Please point out the mistake in my above code and help me figure out the solution.

Please note that `console.log()` is presenting results just as expected, i.e., the conditions are getting appropriately fulfilled and the loop is appropriately completing its journey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display` will/does not work with `animate`. You can instead use `show()` and `hide()` in addition to the other answer.

From http://api.jquery.com/animate/:

*Note: Unlike shorthand animation methods such as .slideDown() and .fadeIn(), the .animate() method does not make hidden elements visible as part of the effect. For example, given $( "someElement" ).hide().animate({height: "20px"}, 500), the animation will run, but the element will remain hidden.*

Answer (score 1):

Instead of animate here you can use jquery .fadeIn() .fadeOut() method to show or hide element with a delay.

Display property won't works in jQuery animate.
Refer [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ go through the yellow highlighted note in this link..

Answer (score 1):

display to none/block cannot be animated. Try instead animate the height to 0 with overflow: hidden

Or you can do it with css transitions easily:

```
// hide it
$(".intro-wrapper").addClass('hidescroll');
// show it again
$(".intro-wrapper").removeClass('hidescroll');
```

And then in css:

```
.intro-wrapper {
    transition: height .5s ease-in;
    height: 400px;
}

.intro-wrapper.hidescroll {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```